# For-each loop with fn:tokenize

Tags: xslt, foreach, xslt-2.0, tokenize, saxon

I want to take the value of variable, tokenize it, and loop through the different tokens.
My solutions does not work as expected. I must be misunderstanding what tokenize() actually does.

```
<xsl:variable name="topicCode">1.2.3.4</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="tokenizedTopicCode"><xsl:value-of select="tokenize($topicCode,'\.')"/></xsl:variable>
<mdcomplex name="Topic">
      <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($tokenizedTopicCode)">
           <xsl:if test="position()=1">
               <md name="chaptercode">
                   <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
               </md>
           </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="position()=2">
              <md name="sectioncode">
              <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="concat($tokenizedTopicCode[position()=1],'.',.)"/></xsl:attribute>
               </md>
           </xsl:if>
           <xsl:if test="position()=3">
               <md name="subsectioncode">
                   <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="concat($tokenizedTopicCode[position()=1],'.',$tokenizedTopicCode[position()=2],'.',.)"/></xsl:attribute>
               </md>
           </xsl:if>
           <xsl:if test="position()=4">
               <md name="topiccode">
                   <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="concat($tokenizedTopicCode[position()=1],'.',$tokenizedTopicCode[position()=2],'.',$tokenizedTopicCode[position()=3],.)"/></xsl:attribute>
               </md>
           </xsl:if>                
       </xsl:for-each>
   </mdcomplex>
```

Expected:

```
<mdcomplex name="Topic">
      <md name="chaptercode" value="1"/>
      <md name="sectioncode" value="1.2"/>
      <md name="subsectioncode" value="1.2.3"/>
      <md name="topiccode" value="1.2.3.4"/>
</mdcomplex>
```

Actual:

```
<mdcomplex name="Topic">
    <md name="chaptercode" value="1 2 3 4"/>
</mdcomplex>
```

I also added a `<xsl:message>` right after the start of the `<xsl:for-each>` loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($tokenizedTopicCode)">
                <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:message>
```

I expected it to output the value of the different tokens (1, 2, 3, 4). Instead, it outputs all tokens in one go: "1 2 3 4".

How can I split the variable into the different tokens and loop through them?
I am using Saxon 9.9.1.7 on Oxygen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You at least need `<xsl:variable name="tokenizedTopicCode" select="tokenize($topicCode,'\.')"/>` instead of `<xsl:variable name="tokenizedTopicCode"><xsl:value-of select="tokenize($topicCode,'\.')"/></xsl:variable>`.

I don't see, however, how you expect to select stuff in e.g. `$topicCode` with a positional predicate, that variable is not a sequence of items.

Comment: Thank you. As suggested, I used the select= inside of the variable element, and now it does what I wanted. I was not aware that there is a difference between that and <xsl:value-of> - I thought they were the same. 
About the $topicCode: you are absolutely right, that was a mistake, it should have been $tokenizedTopicCode. I also corrected the problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Key learning points here:

(1) `xsl:value-of` constructs a single text node. You're splitting a string into tokens using tokenize(), and then you're immediately stringing them back together using xsl:value-of.

(2) `xsl:variable`, with no `select` or `as` attribute, constructs an XML document tree. Again that's going to munge your tokens together.

If you want a variable to contain a sequence of strings, do

```
<xsl:variable name="t" select="tokenize(...)" as="xs:string*"/>
```

Technically the `as` attribute here is redundant, but it's generally good practice to include it, because it helps both the human reader and the XSLT compiler spot any mistakes in your code.

Comment: Hello Michael Kay, thanks for the summary. I have never used as in variables before, but I will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="topicCode">1.2.3.4</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="tokenizedTopicCode" select="tokenize($topicCode,'\.')"/>
<xsl:variable name="names" select="('chapter', 'section', 'subsection', 'topic')"/>
<mdcomplex name="Topic">
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to count ($tokenizedTopicCode)">
        <md name="{$names[current()]}code">
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="$tokenizedTopicCode[position() le current()]" separator="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </md>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</mdcomplex>
```

Not sure why you would want to use `distinct-values()` here; isn't `1.1.1.1` a valid topic code?

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. This does indeed work: <xsl:variable name="tokenizedTopicCode" select="tokenize($topicCode,'\.')"/> 
Your solution with the for loop and the names sequence is also very elegant.
I came across distinct-values() while randomly googling the problem. I do not really understand what it does, so I deleted it now.